# Paper.JS - Can´t resize rectangle after it reaches minimum size

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I´ve created a small script based on HitTest example from paperjs.org. The idea is to have a Rectangle and be able to move and resize it. It is almost working but, when I resize it to the minimum size I´ve specified (10x10), for some reason, I´m not able to resize it anymore, even if I release drag event and try again.

```js
var hitOptions = {
 segments: true,
 stroke: true,
 fill: true,
 tolerance: 1
};

project.currentStyle = {
    fillColor: 'green',
    strokeColor: 'black'
};

var rect_a = new Path.Rectangle(new Point(50, 50), 50);

var segment, path, hitType;
var clickPos = null;
var movePath = false;
var minHeight = 10;
var minWidth = 10;

function onMouseDown(event) {
 segment = path = null;
 var hitResult = project.hitTest(event.point, hitOptions);
 if (!hitResult)
  return;

    hitType = hitResult.type;

 if (event.modifiers.shift) {
  if (hitResult.type == 'segment') {
   hitResult.segment.remove();
  };
  return;
 }

 if (hitResult) {
  path = hitResult.item;
  if (hitResult.type == 'segment') {
   segment = hitResult.segment;
  }
 }
 movePath = hitResult.type == 'fill';
 if (movePath) {
  project.activeLayer.addChild(hitResult.item);
 }

 clickPos = checkHitPosition(event);
}

function onMouseMove(event) {
    changeCursor(event);
 project.activeLayer.selected = false;
 if (event.item)
  event.item.selected = true;
}

function onMouseDrag(event) {
 if (hitType == "stroke" || hitType == "segment") {
        resizeRectangle(path, event);
 } else {
  path.position += event.delta;
 }
}

function resizeRectangle(path, event) {
    switch(clickPos) {
        case "SE" :
            resizeBottom(path, event);
            resizeRight(path, event);
            break;
        case "NE" :
            resizeTop(path, event);
            resizeRight(path, event);
            break;
        case "SW" :
            resizeBottom(path, event);
            resizeLeft(path, event);
            break;
        case "NW" :
            resizeTop(path, event);
            resizeLeft(path, event);
            break;
        case "S"  :
            resizeBottom(path, event);
            break;
        case "N"  :
            resizeTop(path, event);
            break;
        case "E"  :
            resizeRight(path, event);
            break;
        case "W"  :
            resizeLeft(path, event);
            break;
    }
}

function resizeTop(path, event) {
    if(path.bounds.height >= minHeight) {
        path.bounds.top += event.delta.y;
    }
}

function resizeBottom(path, event) {
    if(path.bounds.height >= minHeight) {
        path.bounds.bottom += event.delta.y;
    }
}

function resizeLeft(path, event) {
    if(path.bounds.width >= minWidth) {
        path.bounds.left  += event.delta.x;
    }
}

function resizeRight(path, event) {
    if(path.bounds.width >= minWidth) {
        path.bounds.right  += event.delta.x;
    }
}

function checkHitPosition(event) {
    var hitResult = project.hitTest(event.point, hitOptions);
    var clickPosition = null;

    if (hitResult) {
        if (hitResult.type == 'stroke' || hitResult.type == 'segment') {
            var bounds = hitResult.item.bounds;
            var point = hitResult.point;

            if (bounds.top == point.y) {
                clickPosition = "N";
            }

            if (bounds.bottom == point.y) {
                clickPosition = "S";
            }

            if (bounds.left == point.x) {
                clickPosition = "W";
            }

            if (bounds.right == point.x) {
                clickPosition = "E";
            }

            if (bounds.top == point.y && bounds.left == point.x) {
                clickPosition = "NW";
            }

            if (bounds.top == point.y && bounds.right == point.x) {
                clickPosition = "NE";
            }

            if (bounds.bottom == point.y && bounds.left == point.x) {
                clickPosition = "SW";
            }

            if (bounds.bottom == point.y && bounds.right == point.x) {
                clickPosition = "SE";
            }
        } else {
            clickPosition = "C";
        }
    }
    return clickPosition;
};

function changeCursor(event) {
    var hitPosition = checkHitPosition(event);
    if(hitPosition == null ) {
        document.body.style.cursor = "auto";
    } else {
        if (hitPosition == "C") {
            document.body.style.cursor = "all-scroll";
        } else {
            document.body.style.cursor = hitPosition + "-resize";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the code shrinks the rectangle below the minimum sizes (minWidth and minHeight). You can add a line

```
console.log(path.bounds.width, path.bounds.height)
```

at the bottom of resizeRectangle to see how the rectangle becomes smaller than minWidth and minHeight.

Then when each `resizeXYZZY` function is called the check `if(path.bounds.height >= minHeight)` (or width) fails and no change is made so the rectangle can't be made larger again.

To fix it, the resizeTop function needs to work differently:

```
var adj = min(event.delta.y, path.bounds.height-minHeight);
path.bounds.top += adj;
```

And the corresponding changes should be made for resizeBottom, Left, and Right.

This avoids setting the rectangle to be smaller than the minimum and also removes any check that prevents it from growing again.